# Swift: how to add App sharing feature with Extension Sheet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios8-share-extension

I want to add the my app sharing feature in my App. Like The Action Sheet Toggle up with the all the social Media and other app in which i can share my app Url. I try to find the tutorial for that but i can't find the proper tutorial for that. this is what I have Done.

```
func shareApp (){
     let textToShare = "Swift is awesome!  Check out this website about it!"

        if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/") {
            let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite] as [Any]
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

            activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.addToReadingList]

            self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This What i Get.

[image]

So just want to show there Some Social Media options There.

Comment: You need to run the app on an actual device with a couple of installed apps. (e.g. WhatsApp, Telegram, Facebook)

Comment: so my code is perfect you mean that.

Comment: Yes, It looks good as you are also able to see `UIActivityViewController`. You just need to change URL to actual app URL that you want to share.

Comment: ok. i have to setup any permission for that in plist?

Comment: You don't need to set any permissions.

Answer (score 1):

All you have done is right, except you have not added the App url of your appstore link. Add that link like https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/more-customers-app/id1280868223?mt=8 and all your media will be appear in list if those application is installed in iphone.

Comment: ok so my code is perfect? Or need any implement? And i have to give any permission in info.plist or any other procedure to follow? Please explain in brief.

Comment: Check I have shared a code with you below in answer, This shares my App with link to all application which has sharing feature. like mail, facebook. but those application will appear in UIActivityViewController if those application installed in iPhone. in simulator you won't get application try it in real device which has facebook and mail application installed

Answer (score 0):

You have got UIActivityViewController presented now, Just add in text like,

```
func ShareApp()
    {
        let items:[Any] = ["Marketplace of Building Material for Architects, Interior Designers, Contractors and Home Owners. Find Material for your next project. Download  https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/more-customers-app/id1280868223?mt=8"]
        let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
        self.present(ac, animated: true)

}
```